# I'm implementing the Expanding Polytope Algorithm, and I am unsure how to deduce the contact points from a point on the minkowski difference

Tags: algorithm, collision-detection

I've been reading about the EPA from several sources, but they all seem to abruptly stop being useful after the closest point on the minkowski difference to the origin is located.  Most of them say something along the lines of ["With this information, we can then generate the local and global contact points and contact tangents,"](http://allenchou.net/2013/12/game-physics-contact-generation-epa/) but I don't understand how that is even possible, much less how to do it.  I don't see how someone could derive the minuend and subtrahend from a difference alone, and certainly not in a reasonable amount of time.  What is the standard solution to this problem?

I am looking to implement this algorithm in 3D, if that changes the answer. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OP of the blog post here.

The post actually says how to compute the contact point in step 8 of the EPA algorithm:

> Project the origin onto the closest triangle. This is our closest
>   point to the origin on the CSO’s boundary. Compute the barycentric
>   coordinates of this closest point with respect to the vertices from
>   the closest triangle. The barycentric coordinates are coefficients of
>   linear combination of vertices from the closest triangle. Linearly
>   combining the individual support points (original results from
>   individual colliders) corresponding to the vertices from the closest
>   triangle, with the same barycentric coordinates as coefficients, gives
>   us contact points on both colliders in their own model space. We can
>   then convert these contact points to world space.

Allow me to rephrase it here.

Let Ca, Cb, and Cc denote the three vertices of the triangle of the CSO that contains the closest point, denoted Cp, on the CSO boundary to the origin.

Compute the barycentric coordinate (x, y, z) of the triangle for Cp.

```
x Ca + y Cb + z Cc = Cp
```

Note that it is required that we keep the original support function results in global space from the two objects (A & B) used to obtain Ca, Cb, and Cc. Let Aa, Ab, and Ac denote the original support function results for object A. Let Ba, Bb, and Bc denote the original support function results for object B.

```
Ca = Aa + Ba
Cb = Ab + Bb
Cc = Ac + Bc
```

Using the barycentric coordinate (x, y, z) obtained earlier to linearly combine the original support function results from object A & B, we can compute the contact points on both objects, denoted Ap and Bp:

```
Ap = x Aa + y Ab + z Ac
Bp = x Ba + y Bb + z Bc
```

I hope this clarifies the computation process for you.

Comment: Sorry for the _huge_ delay, I haven't been checking up on my account for a while, but thanks for the response!  It's very helpful, and sorry for implying that your blog was unhelpful, in fact it was the most helpful source I could find.  I guess I didn't quite understand the process, but you've cleared it up.